# How to prevent DDoS when asking for authentication?

Tags: android, authentication, denial-of-service

I'm developing an Android app that requests a certain-format username authentication (I've previously sent him this username) in my server to continue.  The thing is that I'm worried that someone, by making tons of these authentication calls to my server, may DDoS it.

I haven't found anything clear so that's why I'm asking: Any ideas of how to prevent it?

---

What I've thought is of making a check of that username on runtime (for instance, that it has to have 3 numbers, have a certain number of letters, etc.), but on server's side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless they're making thousands of request per second (which I'm pretty sure a person can't do manually), the likelihood you'd experience a "DDoS" (which is not really the term to use, here) or even slight lag from the server is pretty slim to none. If you are experiencing that, then you have some serious issues to work out in your code and should post a different question for help.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is listening to a port, then it can **always** be flooded with messages, bogus or not. The trick to avoid (or at least minimize) a denial of service condition is to make sure that faulty/malicious requests are discarded as quickly as possible and the connection released. So design your authentication scheme with that in mind, making sure that any acquired resources (sockets, objects, etc.) are released and/or made reusable as soon as you've determined that authentication has failed.